# What's the theoretical max output of the National Ignition Facility (NIF)?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics

With the latest Ignition event at the [National Ignition Facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Ignition_Facility) (NIF) producing 3.5Mj of energy, I'm curious to know. Using the pellets that they are, what's the maximum energy they could produce, assuming everything went absolutely perfectly and they had a full and clean ignition?

Comment: Well, per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Ignition_Facility, the chamber is only designed for 45MJ output.

Comment: Make the total theoretical energy balance of the reactions on the components present.